# Connection pooling not working with ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server for Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv, unixodbc

We have just installed the latest SQL 13 drivers and the latest sqlsrv and sqlsrv_pdo PHP extensions. Connection pooling does not seem to be working.

- OS: CentOS 7.2
- PHP:PHP 7.0.12
- SQL Driver: ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server

Summary of test: We created a test script which will connect to the DB. After the script executes the connection is closed, confirmed by the DB.

odbcinst.ini:

```
[ODBC]
Pooling = Yes

[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.1.0
UsageCount=1
CPTimeout=120
```

Test script which includes some timing (ms):

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
function printElapsedTimeSinceLastEvent($event=''){
    global $startTime;
    $elapsed = microtime(true) - $startTime;
    echo $event . round($elapsed*1000) ."\n";
    $startTime = microtime(true);
}

// Connection sqlsrv driver
$pdo = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=10.12.12.123;database=aDatabaseName",'coolUser','someAwesomePassword');
printElapsedTimeSinceLastEvent("Connected: ");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM users");
$stmt->execute();
printElapsedTimeSinceLastEvent("Execute: ");
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
printElapsedTimeSinceLastEvent("Fetch: ");
```

3 consecutive outputs of script:

```
Connected: 149
Execute: 109
Fetch: 2

Connected: 149
Execute: 100
Fetch: 2

Connected: 152
Execute: 108
Fetch: 2
```

Using SQL Studio and running EXEC sp_who2 we can see the connections are closed after each run. Using sqlsrv on Windows does keep connections open as it expected and does show up in sp_who2 output.

On Windows where we confirmed connection pooling does exist the connection time is significantly faster as one would expect with connection pooling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft acknowledged the bug and has since released a new version which supports pooling.